# -bash: /usr/local/bin/gem: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/ruby/2.2.0/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails-3, parse-platform, rubygems, cocoapods

when e try to update in terminal

```
gem update --system
```

I got this error

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/gem: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/ruby/2.2.0/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory..
```

how to fix this pls?

Comment: Which OS do you use? It seams to me that is OS issue. If you take a look to `/usr/local/bin/gem` by `cat /usr/local/bin/gem` maybe you will find at first line something like `#!@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/ruby/2.2.0/bin/ruby` where `HOMEBREW_CELLAR` should be a kind of variable that will be replace by a real place for ruby root. I'm not either a ruby expert and iOS but you should look why there aren't any substitution for `@@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@`

Comment: Im using now 10.10 yosemite, so in order to replace is there any method using terminal ?

Comment: Sorry, but I stopped to use mac 15 years ago :)

Comment: I was getting the same error after updating os x to yosemite. the problem was neither homebrew or rubygems, but some libraries like openssl, that I re-installed. This was the actual error:
    /private/var/folders/93/cqzrrzdx2g9g5bzc1k53bt8r0000gn/T/ruby-build.20150315003954.23990/ruby-2.2.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/private/var/folders/93/cqzrrzdx2g9g5bzc1k53bt8r0000gn/T/ruby-build.20150315003954.23990/ruby-2.2.1/.ext/x86_64-darwin14/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)